# Django - AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS'

Tags: python, django, nginx

I have got a python App on production that crashed. When trying to open the website I get a 502 bad gateway. After trying to restart the django app using `python manage.py restart` I got the following error.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):


File "manage.py", line 23, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 316, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 97, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/ringier/expat/expat/expat/expat/settings/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from expat.settings.production import *
  File "/ringier/expat/expat/expat/expat/settings/production.py", line 4, in <module>
    from expat.settings.base import *
  File "/ringier/expat/expat/expat/expat/settings/base.py", line 89, in <module>
    TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = global_settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS + (
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS'
```

I didn't change anything on the code nor the configs, I don't know why this is happening. I checked similar errors but they didn't resolve this issue.

Thanks

EDIT :

base.py

```
...
from django.conf import global_settings
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = global_settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS + (
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'home.context_processors.system_config',)
...
```

global_settings = https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/conf/global_settings.py

EDIT 2:

I removed the call to global_settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS. After doing that I had to install many of the modules called from base.py, which is very strange because the website was working perfectly and I don't know how come those modules were missing...
After installing all the modules I could I reached the point where I can't install the module for postgres

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 23, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 341, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 199, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 52, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 119, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 316, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 214, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 211, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 115, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 24, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named psycopg2
```

I would really appreciate help as the website is on prod and now down for more than 12hours.

Comment: Any chance you can include the code? The 'base.py' (at least includes and around the error line) + the global_settings included file

Comment: There is no 'TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS' on the global_settings file

Comment: @AdrianoMartins I added the code above, I can't find the const TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS in global_settings.py. I'm not sure, maybe some configuration got overwritten and now the App is looking on the wrong place ?

Comment: It looks like you have upgraded Django to 1.10, which has removed `global_settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`. Either downgrade Django, or update your settings. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39315348/cannot-import-name-template-context-processors/39315587#39315587) should help.

Comment: @Alasdair I've removed the call to global_settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS but now none of the other modules can be found. it's seems like Django don't know where to get it's modules

Comment: Please update your question with the new error.

Comment: Check your configurations and make sure you're not running in 'test'

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you did not restart Django in the same virtual environment as before, since the Django version appears to have changed and you are getting import errors for `psycopg2`.

It sounds like you might be using `runserver` in production. You should not do this, it's insecure. The [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/) describe how to deploy Django properly.

Comment: I don't think they used Virtualenv when setting up the project. when I do for example `lsvirtualenv` it says command not found. However now when I do the `python manage.py restart` no error is shown. but the website is still down with error 502